# TI Design note Differential to Single-Ended Conversion clarification needed

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog

The below image is from [this TI design note](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduez8b/tiduez8b.pdf?ts=1684745320162&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

[image]

When I did my own calculation for \$V_\text{out}\$, I obtained a different equation (given below).

$$V_\text{out} = (V_\text{outP} - V_\text{outN}) \times \frac{R_4}{R_3} + V_\text{ref}$$

Is the mistake from TI or my end?

Comment: Where are your R1 and R2? Please show calculation steps.

Comment: My R1 and R2 is located in the same place as shown in the above figure

Comment: In the equation I should say.

Comment: Why do you think R1 and R2 cancel out? You haven't shown that.

Comment: @TimWilliams,I also assumed R1=R4 and R2 = R3. If you can try from your end to derive the equation for Vout,will be helpful

Comment: @Justme,In the TI document they assumed R1=R4 and R2 = R3 and derive the equation for Vout

Comment: What about the capacitors? Where are they factored in?

Comment: @Andyaka,please ignore those caps.Consider as open

Answer (score 4):

I believe your equation is correct. TI's equation has a -ve sign missing before VoutN. They reference an application brief document below the equation

[image]

In that, you can see that they correct the mistake in equation 2

[image]